# Rails 4 Relation#first with finder options is deprecated - while using #where

Tags: activerecord, deprecated, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code in my controller:

```
def index
  @purchases = Purchase.all
  @purchases = @purchases.where(user_id: current_user.id) unless current_user.admin
  @purchases = @purchases.paginate(per_page: 30, page: params[:page])
end
```

Which results in the following deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#first with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call #first on it instead.
```

I don't really understand why, because I don't use #first anywhere. I should also point out that the problem is definitely in the second line inside the `#index` action - commenting it out removes the deprecation.

Answer (score 4):

This was devise. Obviously method `#current_user` was using a deprecated AR query. Use 'rails4' branch.